# mysql replication on windows server

Tags: mysql, replication, windows

How to setup replication(Master/slave) in MySQL 5.6 while both servers are windows based?
All the things i have fond are Linux based replication. kindly someone help who experienced replication with windows based server.

Answer (score 10):

Replication setup on a windows server is equivalent to doing it in other systems: [The official manual provides you a detailed guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-howto.html). In short:

1. Configure on both servers a different server-id, and activate the binary log on the master. If it is not already done, the most typical way to do that is modify the my.ini file and restart the service (net restart mysql):

   ```
   [mysqld]
   log-bin
   server-id = 1
   ```

   Make also sure that the master is accesible from the slave node and it is **not bound to localhost** (`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`)
2. Create a user on the master for the slave to connect with REPLICATION SLAVE privileges (use MySQL-command line for this):

   ```
   mysql master> CREATE USER 'user_name'@'ip.of.the.slave' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   mysql master> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'user_name'@'ip.of.the.slave';
   ```
3. Make a backup of the master and apply it to the slave. There are several ways to do that (stopping the server and copying the files works), but the easiest would be to se mysqldump (navigate to the bin directory of your sql-server installation (f.e. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin). Also you may need to provide credentials by appending this to both commands: -uroot -pPassword)

   ```
   (on the master windows command line) mysqldump --all-databases --master-data > dump.sql
   (on the slave windows command line ) mysql < dump.sql
   ```
4. At the beginning the dump.sql you will find a line like this:

   ```
   -- CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'file_name', MASTER_LOG_POS = file_pos;
   ```

   Use those parameters to configure the replication on the slave:

   ```
   mysql slave> CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'ip.of.the.master',
                    MASTER_USER = 'user_name_you_just_created',
                    MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password_you_just_defined',
                    MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'file_name',
                    MASTER_LOG_POS = file_pos;
   ```

   (beware, no quotes for integers, like `MASTER_LOG_POS`).
5. If everything is ok until now, just start replication on the slave:

   ```
   mysql slave> START SLAVE;
   ```

   To check that it is running, execute:

   ```
   mysql slave> SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
   ```

   And look for:

   ```
      Slave_IO_Running: Yes
     Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
   ```

GTID-based replication is a bit different, and I have not mentioned it.

Comment: Could you explain more detail about the `file_name`? Is it user defined?

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho You can find the `file_name` and `file_pos` by executing this query on the master `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`