# How to replicate MySql database between two 2012 server

Tags: mysql, join

I am setting up a disaster recovery strategy for two 2012 servers DB1 and DB2 in one location and may be later I plan to set them in different locations, I want DB2 to take control incase of of DB1 failure.
They are installed with MySql 5.5 database application and for now DB2 has no data.

How can can I replicate and synch these two servers? and create backups from DB2?

Comment: Does "2012" mean that the OS is Windows 2012 Server?

Comment: YES ypercube, sorryI was away for quite sometime

Answer (score 0):

The replication process on windows servers is similar to doing it in any other server system.

First of all I would recommend reading the official MySQL replication documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html) and then check out this similar question from a while ago. ([mysql replication on windows server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73467/mysql-replication-on-windows-server))

Personally I would suggest using tools that allow you to replicate data between database servers. They can save you all the messy work and even impove performance.

When I wanted to replicate my MySQL database to Amazon Redshift data warehouse (https://www.alooma.com/integrations/mysql/redshift) I used a tool called Alooma that supports several replication methods and provides a 'Near Realtime View' which allows you to query the latest snapshot of your database in your data warehouse.